# Is there any benefit to keeping resources in my clan castle?

Tags: clash-of-clans

With the new clan wars update, any resources won will stay in your clan castle until you withdraw them. When you withdraw them, the game asks "are you sure?" which led me to wonder if there is any reason to keep them inside the clan castle.

What benefit, if any, is there to keeping resources in your clan castle?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since clan castles generally have more hp than loot storage, they will be harder to be destroyed completely, and they will only receive loot once they have fully destroyed it.

According to [this](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Treasury) only 3% of the loot stored in your clan castle can be taken during a raid. Whereas 20% can be stolen from your gold storage and elixir storage according to the [wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Elixir_Storage).

Therefore it is safer to keep your loot in the clan castle if you don't plan on spending it immediately.

Comment: Also, keeping loot in your CC spreads out the loot in your base and lowers the amount in each individual building.

Answer (score 13):

miva2 points out very good reasons, but also there's the practical side. It's a good idea to have your gold/elixir/dark elixir in whichever is guarded better (or closest to the center of your base). Additionally, goblins don't target your clan castle, because it's not classified as a storage. So, overall, I think it's better to keep your resources in your clan castle if you don't need them immediately.

Comment: +1 for good point about goblins.  I'm not sure the giants point is relevant, though - they won't attack the places it'd go if you did take it out (gold or elixir storage), either.

Answer (score 8):

There is another benefit aside from the one that miva2 mentions about the Clan Castle only being loot-able to 10% rather than the normal 20%.

This other benefit is that it can hold more resources than your current storage space allows. If you have max gold storage of 1,000,000 for example and currently have 900,000 and you win 200,000 then the clan castle allows you to store that extra 100,000 until you've spent the gold you have. Also you can only collect as much loot as you have room for in storage. So if in the previous example you collected from your clan castle 100,000 of those resources would go into your stores and the remaining 100,000 would stay in your clan castle

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the others, but I think there's one exception that rule. If you have more resources than the amount required to reach the loot cap, it is better to collect it. For example, at TH8 300k is the cap and you need to have around 2.4 million of each resource to reach it. If you leave your war bonus in the CC, you will lose 7% of it + 300k. If you collect it, you will only lose 300k.

Comment: This is a very good point which others haven't mentioned yet.

Answer (score 1):

If removing resources from your clan castle fills one of your storages the remainder of the resources stays in the clan castle until you make room in your storage. After which the remainder can be removed from the castle.

Comment: you're repeating what Orwell already explained...